# AFNetworking JSON parsing - fails of unknown reason

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, afnetworking

im trying to parse some JSON. for simplicity ill explain using the default example at github:
when running:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://httpbin.org/ip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(
    NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse     *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"IP Address: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"origin"]);
    } failure:nil];

[operation start];
```

i get the correct output logged. however, when i copy the example's content (which is basically 1 element) to a txt or html file (so URLWithString gets @"http:// my server address /file.txt"), putting it on my testing server and trying to prase from there, i get no output. what is wrong with this? thanks for your time!

(note: if i go to http:// my server address /file.txt i can see the contents there clearly so that's not the problem)

edit: as suggested, the content is:
"{
  "origin": "10.44.119.100"
}"

Comment: You should add the exact content you copied into your question so people can see what that looks like.

Comment: thanks Firoze! even though that could be found at the URLWithString but it is nicer to just see it there.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably has something to do with the fact that you're serving content as a text file (`.txt`) rather than as JSON (`Content-Type: application.json` / `.json` extension). AFNetworking is strict about HTTP standards in order to guard against unexpected behavior. Either set the correct `Content-Type` header on your server, or (as a hack) do `AFJSONRequestOperation +addAcceptableContentTypes:` adding `text/plain`.

As a meta note: when asking a question on Stack Overflow, specifics matter. If you had posted the error you were seeing in the console, it would be much easier to determine what the problem was. Likewise, *approximate* code is not *actual* code; if you have a problem, be specific about exactly what's going on. Details matter.

Answer (score -1):

You should encode the json data first and then write it into the text file and when you are reading the data from file... decode the data first...

**EDIT:**
replace JSON operation with simple http and check if you are able to get data from there... 
and if you are then JSONOperation basically is seeking for json response which is not in text file... i guess

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
 {

     NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

 }];

[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{


    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@" Success %@",str);
   // id response = AFJSONDecode(responseObject, nil);

    [self requestSucceed:response];
}
                                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
}];
```

Comment: the data at the first and second location is the same and is given as
    {
      "origin": "10.44.119.100" 
    }

Comment: @Zephyer I have edited answer... kindly implement this way and see if you get any response.